# Lazarus on Windows: Cannot load PostgreSQL Client Library "libpq.dll"

Tags: windows, postgresql, lazarus, postgresql-9.5

[Cannot load PostgreSQL Client Library "libpq.dll" Check your installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKJHy.png)

I am just a casual programmer (I guess) and I am totally a newbie to PostgreSQL and lazarus. I am recreating a little project I learned in an Intership for our school organization which uses a database so I am reading tutorials how to connect a PostgreSQL database to a lazarus application. Unluckily, I experience this error while following a tutorial. Lazarus cannot load PostgreSQL client library "libpq.dll". I have already searched the net on how to fix it like this [article](http://wiki.freepascal.org/postgres#Error:_.22Can_not_load_PostgreQL_client_library_.22libpq.dll.22.22) but no avail. I have checked PostgreSQL's lib folder in program files and nothing's wrong, libpq.dll is there. Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds as if `libpq.dll` is not on the system `PATH`

Comment: You mean in the system32 folder?

Comment: [There are a number of posts about this in the Lazarus forums](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=Lazarus+on+Windows:+Cannot+load+PostgreSQL+Client+Library+%22libpq.dll%22+site:forum.lazarus.freepascal.org&num=100&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO0eS2zprKAhXIMyYKHdEWA-oQrQIIKCgEMAA&biw=1494&bih=967). Considering reviewing those and asking there if the exists posts don't solve your issue.

Comment: No. Do **not** put stuff in `system32`. Add the directory where the dll is, to the `PATH` variable.

Comment: I have already put it there. C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\lib in the Path Variable but the error still shows up

Comment: Sorry my bad. Thanks for answering Mark Stosberg and  a_horse_with_no_name, I have mistakenly put the files in the lib in my projects directory, it should be the files in the bin.